# How I can get count of likes from page on my website?

Tags: facebook, plugins, social-media

How I can get count of likes from page on my website?
In my case I have page with news list, for example.
And I want to show under each news count of likes, is there an easy and simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code you can use for that

```
<?php require_once 'src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));


    $fanpage = $_GET["fanpage_id"]; 
    $width = $_GET["width"]; 
    $height = $_GET["height"];
    $fontfamily = $_GET["fontfamily"];
    $fontsize = $_GET["fontsize"]; 
    $fontcolor = $_GET["fontcolor"]; 
    $backgroundcolor = $_GET["backgroundcolor"]; 
    $backgroundimage = $_GET["backgroundimage"]; 


    $result = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => 'select fan_count from page where page_id = '.$fanpage.''
    ));

    $fb_fans = $result[0]['fan_count'];

    echo '<style>
    #likes{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#000;
        }
    </style>
    ';


    echo '<div id="likes">';
    echo ''.$fb_fans.'';
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Wow, big thanks! But there is one more question - Where I can read about using page_id parameter? I can't find in documentation (my English not perfect) how to set page_id permanently in like button elemnt:

<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

Is this must be somewhere there or somewhere else? It parameter directly links "like" with some page on my website, right? So, help me please with info about that parameter!

Comment: Hello @AndreySamozhenkov do you still need asistance ? sorry for my late reaction